# Return with else or not

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Is there any performance difference between the two functions, is one considered *more* correct? Is there a best practice or rule of thumb I am missing? ExampleB seems more succinct to me and thus more readable, yet the logic does not seem as tightly tied together and is therefore not as explicit.

```
function exampleA() {
  if( true ) {
    return //do this;
  } else {
    return //do that;
  }
};
```

Versus

```
function exampleB(){
  if( true ) {
    return //do this;
  }
  return //do that;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running them on http://jsperf.com ?

Comment: Check it out here: http://jsperf.com/unneeded-else-performance (The second is 1.11% faster for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is one considered more correct? Is there a best practice or rule of
>   thumb I am missing

Don't need the `else`. Programmers we're lazy, so second version is better, more concise. But if something returns `true` or `false` or a truthy or falsy value, then you can return the expression:

```
if (something) { // Meh
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}

if (something) return true; // OK
return false;

return something; // Nice
```

> Is there any performance difference between the two functions

I think the performance is irrelevant, it's more about best practice and making your code more concise using early returns when possible.

Comment: He also asks -- _is one considered more correct? Is there a best practice or rule of thumb I am missing?_

Comment: The OP doesn't say he returns a bool.

Comment: It also doesn't return something, it just quits the function.

Comment: `Is there a best practice or rule of thumb I am missing?`. I think it's a little broader than that.

Comment: @elclanrs: If that were the only part of the question, we'd have closed it by now, because it's subjective.

Comment: It is subjective but also about best practice I guess. I mean, the performance difference (if any) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've always gone for the second. I don't think there is really any semantic difficulty in the second example, and it's a few less characters. Following the "Less Ink" approach, I'd go for Example B.

That said, if this example is for absolute beginner programmers, they might need that `else` clause to make heads or tails of it. I guess it comes down to context.

[image]

Performance wise, as you can see from above. the second is fastest by `0.08%`, so not a giant performance difference. In fact, this difference could be based on variables other than this code, so really the performance difference is effectively `0`.

Comment: This may only apply for this boolean check and the browser you tested it on.

Comment: I think I meant to put that. It's early; thanks for reminding me. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any performance difference between the two functions

No, not in any significant or consistent way - Check on jsPerf: [When test is true](http://jsperf.com/else-vs-just-return) | [When test is false](http://jsperf.com/else-vs-just-return/2):

True:

[image: jsPerf results showing it's basically a tie when test is true]

False:

[image: jsPerf results showing it's basically a tie when test is false]

> ...is one considered more correct?

That's a style question. Style questions aren't suitable to SO's format.

Comment: The functions in your test return before they hit the else part---but it doesn't make much difference anyway: http://jsperf.com/else-vs-just-return/2

Comment: @Juhana: Doh! I meant to test both cases, and forgot! Thanks, I've put that in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second one (and remove the last return statement which has no purpose if it returns nothing).

The reason is :

You don't have to indend the code there, so it'll be more likely readable (overall if you have some long lines of code).